# iAd в приложениях iOS

Tags: xcode, iphone, objective-c

Доброго дня.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем : Использую iAd в приложении для iPhone , и при запуске приложения в симуляторе xcode 4 нет ни "Test Advertisement", ни самого банера. Может ли это быть связано с отсутствием сертификата разработчика , либо проблема заключается в чем-то дугом?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для демонстрации в симуляторе не нужен сертификат или что-то еще.

[iAdSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198): вверху нажмите на "dowload sample code" и получите код тестовых приложений с различными баннерами.